# After __toString() no code is working in php

Tags: php

In following code after __toString() the php code is not working why ?

```
class Student{

    private $name;
    private $roll_no;

    function __construct($name,$roll_no){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->roll_no = $roll_no;
    }

    public function display(){
        echo "Name :".$this->name;
        echo "<br> Roll No :".$this->roll_no."<br><br>";
    }


    function __toString(){
        $this->display();
    }

}

$std1 = new Student("Bob" , 1);
echo $std1;
$std2 = new Student("John" , 2);
echo $std2;
$std3 = new Student("Tony" , 3);
echo $std3;
$std4 = new Student("Teena" , 4);
echo $std4;
```

The out put in browser is bellow : 
 Name :Bob 
Roll No :1 
 Rest of the lines are not working;

Comment: It seems std1 here contains nothing, lead to an exception in echo statement.

Comment: i do try{}catch(){} no exception is there

Comment: you should always return a string in tostring function, instead of echoing it. Maybe your PHP configuration suppresses further error messages.

Comment: thaks keyu Gan. I got it...!

Comment: Following @KeyuGan comment, when developing you should always print ALL error messages; this would prevent you from getting this kind of "strange" behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Method **__toString** should return String not call output function. In Your code you done something like **echo echo**, because inside method **display** echo is called again. Change **__toString** to:

```
return  $this->display();
```

and **display** method to:

```
return "Name :".$this->name."<br> Roll No :".$this->roll_no."<br><br>";
```

This solution fixes Your errors, but You should change display method name to something more matching its current behavior like getString().

---

Looking at naming conversion ( **display method name** ) most logical would be  such approach:

```
class Student{

private $name;
private $roll_no;

function __construct($name,$roll_no){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->roll_no = $roll_no;
}

public function display(){
    echo $this; //conversion to string and echo
}


function __toString(){
    return "Name :".$this->name."<br> Roll No :".$this->roll_no."<br><br>";
}

}
```

So I use inside **display** method conversion to String by **__toString**. Current usage would be:

```
$std1=new Student("Bob" , 1);
$std1.display();
//or the same:
echo $std1; //the same thing like $std1.display();
```

Comment: If method is called display, it should display contents somewhere instead of returning displayable string. So you should move formatting to __toString method and call echo $this from display method.

Comment: @SamiKorhonen sorry but __toString should not output anything, it should do conversion complex structure to String and return it, echo inside it is very wrong thing. He named method display, if so he should use it as public method not inside toString, then it has a sense. But when i look on his code, problem was in doing echo outside and inside.

Comment: I didn't say that toString should output anything - display should. You have changed your answer since I made my comment

Comment: @SamiKorhonen You comment was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Student{

private $name;
private $roll_no;

function __construct($name,$roll_no){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->roll_no = $roll_no;
}

public function display(){
    return "Name :".$this->name."<br> Roll No :".$this->roll_no."<br><br>";
}


function __toString(){
  return $this->display();
}

}

$std1 = new Student("Bob" , 1);
echo $std1;
$std2 = new Student("John" , 2);
echo $std2;
$std3 = new Student("Tony" , 3);
echo $std3;
$std4 = new Student("Teena" , 4);
echo $std4;
```